# evaluate $\int\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1-2x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate $\int\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1-2x}}dx$

This is what I got so far:

Let $u$ = $1-2x$

$x$ = $\frac{u-1}{-2}$

$du$ = $-2$  $dx$

$\frac{-du}{2}$ = $dx$

Therefore,

$\int\frac{3\frac{u-1}{-2}}{\sqrt{u}}\frac{-du}{2}$

$\int\frac{3(u-1)}{-2\sqrt{u}}\frac{-du}{2}$

$\frac{3}{4}\int\frac{(u-1)}{\sqrt{u}}{du}{}$

$\frac{3}{4}\int\frac{u}{{u^\frac{1}{2}}}-\frac{1}{{u^\frac{1}{2}}}{du}$

$\frac{3}{4}\int u^\frac{1}{2} -u^\frac{-1}{2}{du}$

$\frac{3}{4}[\frac{2}{3}u^\frac{3}{2} -2u^\frac{1}{2}]+C$

$\frac{6}{12}u^\frac{3}{2} -\frac{6}{4}u^\frac{1}{2}+C$

$\frac{1}{2}u^\frac{3}{2} -\frac{3}{2}u^\frac{1}{2}+C$

$\frac{1}{2}u^\frac{3}{2} -\frac{3}{2}u^\frac{1}{2}+C$

$\frac{u^\frac{3}{2}-3u^\frac{1}{2}}{2}+C$

$\frac{\sqrt{u^3}-3\sqrt{u}}{2}+C$

$\frac{\sqrt{(1-2x)^3}-3\sqrt{1-2x}}{2}+C$

The answer I'm supposed to get is $-\sqrt{1-2x} {(x+1)}+C$

Comment: You are right.  If you are trying to check with an answer in the back of the book or something like that, remember that even if it looks different you may be able to show that the two answers are actually the same by doing some careful algebra.  This often happens with integrals.  And you can always check your final answer by differentiating with respect to $x$ and making sure you get $3x/\sqrt{1-2x}$.

Comment: Right, I forgot to add the constant, I changed it now.

Comment: it is right, please add the assumed right answer

Comment: @Semsem, I will do so, shortly.

Comment: This _could_ be written as $ \ \frac{3}{4} \ u^{1/2} \ (\frac{2}{3}u - 2 ) \ + \ C \ , $ so the solver may have written their answer based on that...

Comment: So I added the rest of answer, but I don't see how can I simplify my answer from what I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is
$$\sqrt{(1-2x)^3}=\sqrt{(1-2x)(1-2x)^2}=\sqrt{(1-2x)}\sqrt{(1-2x)^2}=\color{red}{\sqrt{(1-2x)}}(1-2x)
\\=\frac{\color{red}{\sqrt{(1-2x)}}(1-2x)-3\color{red}{\sqrt{1-2x}}}{2}+C
\\=\sqrt{1-2x}[\frac{(1-2x)-3}{2}]+C
\\=-\sqrt{1-2x}[x+1]+C$$
this is the correct answer, and your book has a typo.

Comment: How did you get the first equation to the second?

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to add the minus in the answer. It's been changed now.

Comment: I still don't understand how you got my answer to your first equation. How did you get $\sqrt{(1-2x)^3}$  to $\sqrt{1-2x}(1-2x)$?

Comment: Is it clear now, @Mark

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks!

Comment: It's an integration problem, but I don't see an integral anywhere in the answer. I do see a $+C$ which seems to appear out of nowhere. Incomprehensible.